# How to use a function outside a class as a property inside a class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, abc

I'm having some problems. How we can define a function outside of a function that can be used in a class property? Also, how we can insert the `self` parameter into the function signature? I would like to visualize it like this:

```
>>> def a(self, x):   #I thought maybe class will give "self" to this property function
...     print(self)
... 
>>> class aa:
...     def __init__(self):
...         pass
...     @a
...     def p():
...         print('in it')
... 
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    File "<stdin>", line 4, in aa
    TypeError: a() missing 1 required positional argument: 'x'
```

I want to define a function outside but to use inside of a class. Like a class's method as a property. How can I do this?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking for. Do you want to actually use `property` to call the `a` function whenever some attribute of an instance of `aa` get accessed? Or are you just using `property` as an example of a decorator that often gets applied with `@property`? Because you can do either of those things, if you understand which you want. You can also just copy a function defined outside of a class into the class and use it as a regular method (with no decorators or properties involved)!

Comment: Does this help?: https://docs.python.org/3.7/howto/descriptor.html

Comment: first of it.I want to get class's atributes

Answer (score 3):

It's not really clear what you want your out-of-class function to do. There are a bunch of possibilities, but you may not know the terminology yet to describe it to us.

Here's the three I think are most likely:

1. You may want your function to be a **decorator**. That means you can apply it to a method with `@decorator` syntax to other functions, including methods in a class.

   For this to work, your function needs to be written to accept a function object as its only argument. Whatever it returns is what will replace the function or method it was being called on, so usually you want to return a callable, but you could instead return a descriptor like `property` does. Try something like this:

   ```
   def decorator(func):
       def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
           print("in the wrapper")
           result = func(self, *args, **kwargs)
           print("wrapper is done")
           return result
       return wrapper

   class Foo:
       @decorator
       def foo(self, x):
           print("in foo(), x is", x)

   f = Foo()
   f.foo(1) # prints three messages
   ```

   When you call the `foo` method, you're actually going to be calling the `wrapper` method that the decorator returned after it was applied to the original method (`func`). Because of how we wrote the wrapper, it will call `func` so the original method prints out its message too.
2. You may want to use `property` (a **descriptor** type) to call your out-of-class function. This is a less common way of using `property` than applying it as a decorator on a method, but it's not impossible. You could even have two different functions, one to be called when requesting the attribute, the other than will be called when setting it (but I'll demonstrate with just the getter):

   ```
   def getter(obj):
       print("in the getter")
       return 1

   class Foo2:
       foo = property(getter)

   f2 = Foo2()
   print(f2.foo) # prints a message from the getter function first, then prints 1
   ```

   Note that you can't use `@decorator` syntax when building a property this way. That is only legal syntax immediately before a function definition, and we're not defining any functions that way inside our class.
3. You may just want to **copy a function** defined outside of the class into it, without any decorator or property nonsense. This is the easiest one to do, it's just a simple assignment:

   ```
   def func(self, x):
       print("x is", x)

   class Foo3:
       method = func  # just assign the global to a name in the class body
       func = func    # you can even use the same name if you don't mind confusing people

   f3 = Foo3()
   f3.method(1)
   f3.func(2)
   ```

Comment: For the first case, how is self passed to wrapper function? Isn't it passed when method is called via object like `obj.func()`? Is it because as you said the wrapper function replaces the original function?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create a property that uses a function defined outside your class, it would be something like this:

```
def myfunc(self):
    return self._p

class Foo:
    def __init__(self, p):
        self._p = p
    p = property(myfunc)

f = Foo("Alpha")
f.p # gives "Alpha"
```

`property` accepts a function as its (first) argument. The function should have `self` as a parameter, and should return the value that you want the property to evaluate to.

Comment: property created.but when im trying to use it like @p , it gives property is not callable..

Comment: @Günel Why are you putting `@p` ?

Comment: essentiallyproblem is that i want to define a function outside and i want to use it in class as property that "will take a method(function in class)" and will return anything.And in this function I also want to work with self.

Comment: You're using the word property to mean something other than a property, and that is very unclear.

Comment: yes I said already.Maybe not property, but like property .I will use this with "@" statement..Will take a method of class and self....is clear mr?

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to accomplish. I am not convinced that you know either.